# FabricJS React clipTO

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

Hey I'm using React and fabricjs with react-fabricjs npm package I just wanted to know how do you use the `clipTo` function with the React syntax in a React component, I can't seem to call the `clipTo` function correctly:

```
var shape = canvas.item(0);
canvas.remove(shape);
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
  shape.render(ctx);
};
```

or this

```
clipTo: function (ctx) {
    ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
}
```

but inside a react component like this:

```
<Image
src="http://i.imgur.com/jZsNUCi.jpg"
width={300}
height={300}
left={0}
top={500}
    clipTo= SOMETHING!!
/>
```

Comment: I have no idea why you would like to use that package.
React manages the DOM, fabricjs lives to one dom element and modify pixels. The package does not look mantained and fabric got lot of updates lately.